# Using nTwitter to reply to a Tweet with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, bots, ntwitter

I have created a very simple twitter bot using `node.js` & `nTwitter`.

It searches for a 'certain word' & replies the user with a random quote. I have managed to do everything right. The code runs & streams perfectly.

But there's a huge drawback. When the bot replies to a tweet, on Twitter it doesn't show it as a conversation.

What it does is just tweet the person who tweeted the 'certain word'. As shown in the snap below although it replied to the user, it's not a conversation & the user has NOT deleted his tweet.

Here's a pic of what I'm talking about:

[image]

And here's my code. The tokens are handled with auth.js

```
var ntwitter = require('ntwitter');
var auth = require('../auth');

var bot = new ntwitter(auth);


var callback = function handleError(error) {
   if (error) {
   console.error('response status:', error.statusCode);
   console.error('data:', error.data);
  }
};

function startStreaming() {

  bot.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'certain word' }, function(stream) {

    console.log('Listening for Tweets...');

    stream.on('data', function(tweet) {

      if (tweet.text.match(/certain\sword/)) {

          bot.updateStatus('@' + tweet.user.screen_name + ' True that' ,
          tweet.user.screen_name , callback);

       }
      });

     });
}


startStreaming();
```

I guess the issue is with `bot.updateStatus()`.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem here is that, technically, you are mentioning that 'user' in a tweet of yours and not replying to his tweet.

Comment: You would have to add a parameter `in_reply_to_status_id` to your request (which is the status id of user's tweet you are replying to.

ref: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update

Comment: You don't need a new method. Within your current `updateStatus` function, in the 2nd parameter, include the `in_reply_to_status_id` that you'll get from the `tweet` object.

Comment: Thanks Akash I tried that but it does the same thing. Maybe I'm not using the code right. Could you please direct me to a in use example of the code please?

Comment: Thanks buddy I figured it out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to add a parameter in_reply_to_status_id to your request (which is the status id of user's tweet you are replying to. Ref: [POST statuses/update](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update)

Here's an example.

```
function startStreaming() {
    bot.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'certain word' }, function(stream) {
        console.log('Listening for Tweets...');
        stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
            if (tweet.text.match('certain word')) {
                bot.updateStatus('@' + tweet.user.screen_name + ' True that' ,
                    {in_reply_to_status_id: tweet.id_str}, callback);
            }
        });
    });
}

startStreaming();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a parameter `in_reply_to_status_id` in order to start a conversation with the Twitter User.

```
function startStreaming() {
    bot.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'certain word' }, function(stream) {
    console.log('Listening for Tweets...');
    stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
        if (tweet.text.match('certain word')) {
            bot.updateStatus('@' + tweet.user.screen_name + ' True that' ,
                {in_reply_to_status_id: tweet.id_str}, callback);
        }
    });
}

startStreaming();
```

Note that `in_reply_to_status_id` won't work if you don't mention the `username` to whom you are replying in the `tweet_text`.
Also, you cant use the same `tweet_text`, or else that would count as spamming.

Source: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update